# C# Algorithm that Re-arranges Chars in a String

Tags: c#, algorithm, string, permutation

I would like a C# algorithm that re-arranges the chars in a string that is dynamic in length. Having trouble finding one and I know there has to be one out there.

The algorithm has to realign elements to form new strings in all possible combinations.

For instance, "cat" would produce the following:
**cat  cta  tca tac act atc**

Comment: Did you check the FAQ? http://stackoverflow.com/tags/algorithm/faq

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a fairly frequently asked question here. Try doing a search on "permutation" and you'll find a lot of good answers about how to do this in various languages.

There is a library of permutation and combination algorithms in C# here:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/Combinatorics.aspx

Answer (score 6):

**There are also the operators I contributed to the [MoreLinq project on Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/#svn/branches/EvenMoreLINQ/MoreLinq) in the `EvenMoreLinq` branch.** If you're just curious about how the algorithm is implemented, you can see the [code for `Permutations<T>()` here](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/branches/EvenMoreLINQ/MoreLinq/Permutations.cs).

They are designed to blend well with LINQ, and use both deferred and streaming evaluation. Permutations is an interesting one, since generating all permutations is a `N!` operation ... which becomes very large for even small values of `N`. Depending on how you generate permutations, you may (or may not) be able to actually enumerate them all.

You'll also find algorithms for other combinatoric operations ([Subsets](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/branches/EvenMoreLINQ/MoreLinq/Subsets.cs), [PermutedSubsets](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/branches/EvenMoreLINQ/MoreLinq/PermutedSubsets.cs), [Cartesian Products](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/branches/EvenMoreLINQ/MoreLinq/Cartesian.cs), [Random Subsets](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/branches/EvenMoreLINQ/MoreLinq/RandomSubset.cs), [Slices](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/branches/EvenMoreLINQ/MoreLinq/Slice.cs), [Partitions](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/branches/EvenMoreLINQ/MoreLinq/Partition.cs), etc) in that same codebase.

Here's how you can use the MoreLinq extensions to permute a sequence. So for instance, you could permute a string (which is treated as a sequence of `char`s) as follows:

```
using MoreLinq;

string input = "cat";
var permutations = input.Permutations();

foreach( var permutation in permutations )
{
    // 'permutation' is a char[] here, so convert back to a string
    Console.WriteLine( new string(permutation) ); 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter String:");
    string inputString = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine();
    List<string> lstAnagrams = new List<string>();
    int numAnagram = 1;

    permute(inputString.ToCharArray(), 0, inputString.Length - 1, lstAnagrams);
    foreach(string anagram in lstAnagrams)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(numAnagram.ToString() + " " + anagram);
        numAnagram++;
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}

static void permute(char[] word, int start, int end, List<string> lstAnagrams)
{
    if (start == end)
        lstAnagrams.Add(string.Join("", word));
    else
    {
        for (int position = start; position <= end; position++)
        {
            swap(ref word[start], ref word[position]);
            permute(word, start + 1, end,lstAnagrams);
            swap(ref word[start], ref word[position]);
        }
    }
}

static void swap(ref char a, ref char b)
{
    char tmp;
    tmp = a;
    a = b;
    b = tmp;
}
```