# IEnumerable to string with space

Tags: c#

I found a nice code to data as anagram of a string but when I am displaying, I am getting in continuous string but I want with space after 3 char.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string result = "";
    var res = "abc".Anagrams();
    foreach(var anagram in res)
    { 
        if(anagram.Count() == 3)
        {
            Console.Write(anagram.MergeToStr());
        }
    }
}

public static string MergeToStr(this IEnumerable<char> chars)
{
    return new string (chars.ToArray());
}
```

**My OutPut**

> abcacbbacbcacabcba

But My expected output should be

> abc acb bac bca cab cba

How can I add spaces to my output?

Comment: Well you don't have anything to add a space - what happens if you just add `Console.Write(" ");` after your current `Console.Write` method? And why do you need to check the count of `anagram`?

Comment: @DaisyShipton guessing [this is the implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4410723/1541563) for `Anagrams()`, in which case the length check would be necessary.

Comment: because if I do not count ,I am getting array of anagram with all char.Eg. a ,b,c,ab etc. and I need only permutation of abc(eg abc,bca etc)

Comment: @DaisyShipton-yes,i am trying to implement the same with my modification

Comment: That seems like a poor implementation of a method called `Anagrams`, IMO. "a" isn't an anagram of "abc"... Ah well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not print any white spaces between your anagrams.

```
 foreach(var anagram in res)
 { 
     if(anagram.Count() != 3) continue;

     Console.Write($"{anagram.MergeToStr()} ");
 }
```

If you do not want to use string interpolation, you can simply:

```
Console.Write(anagram.MergeToStr() + " ");
```

EDIT:
Ordering the response:

```
var res = "abc".Anagrams().Where(x => x.Count() == 3).Select(x => x.MergeToStr()).OrderBy(x => x).ToList();
foreach(var word in res)
{
    Console.Write($"{word} ");
}
```

Comment: thanks but Now I am not getting string value in alphabeticalal order.Can you suggest something for that.i am getting[dog dgo odg ogd gdo god
] when I should get [dgo dog gdo god odg ogd]

Comment: I have edited the response. Make sure to import the Linq namespace. (using System.Linq;). Does this help you?

Answer (score 2):

Below example uses `Linq` and `string.Join` for the required output.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string result = "";
    var res = "abc".Anagrams();
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join("   ", res.Where(a => a.Count() == 3).Select(a => a.MergeToStr()).TrimRight());
}
```

This would produce output as `abc acb bac bca cab cba`

Comment: Thanks but it will also give non alphabetical .I am getting [dog dgo odg ogd gdo god] whereas I am expecting [dgo dog gdo god odg ogd] .any suggestion?